# It still shows old icon in mobile phone run after modify png file in drawable

Tags: android, mobile, icons

I develop a simple program and I want to change the icon. That is the mean to change the ic_launcher.png file in every drawable folder.

I compile in simulator, it can run well. It has changed the new icon. When I install the mobile phone and run, it is still display the old icon. What is the problem?

Comment: Did you uninstall first? What launcher as you using?

Comment: @bonnie is your problem solved with the given solution?

Comment: @bonnie that's great to hear. you are always welcome. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Instead of:

```
<application android:icon="@+drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Just remove "+" sign from `android:icon="@+drawable/ic_launcher"` .

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change icons in all the drawable folders : hdpi/mdpi/ldpi

Your phone might be a hdpi device and you may be changing the icon in ldpi(for example)
.Clean your project and uninstall  the old apk file from device and reinstall the new apk.

Answer (score 1):

If you're updating an app rather than installing for the first time, then the launcher icon won't be replaced. You need to fully uninstall the app and install it fresh.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try that in other mobile phone  ? The problem is maybe in caching but im not sure.

Answer (score 0):

That is really strange, but maybe you have changed only one of icons, i mean that you have to change all versions of icon in res/drawable, res/drawable-hdpi, res/drawable-ldpi, res/drawable-mdpi, res/drawable-xdpi

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps to resolve this problem
1.unistall tthe app  and Restart your phone
2.clean project and build project
3.run the app in the phone to see changed icon of the App